# Apply existing SQL-schema with Groovy or Gradle

Tags: sql, gradle, groovy

I am currently migrating a Maven-project to Gradle. The Maven-project drops and creates a database (for test purposes) and applies an existing SQL-schema to the database.
Is there a smart way to do this with Gradle or Groovy, without executing the SQL within the schema using batches?

Comment: Have you looked at liquibase and flyways? How do you run the DB for your dev-env? Most Docker-Images allow for initial setup with .sql files or scripts...

Comment: Nevermind, the whole project just got cancelled ..
But for future reference: 
We use Postgresql which is running on a server connected to Jenkins. The SQL statements are executed via Maven (sql-maven-plugin). The same goes for applying the schema..